# Simple_html_dom: Can't receive images from large websites?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom.php to get all images from an url (like pinterest does)

```
if($_POST['submit']) {

$url = $_POST['form_url'];
$html = file_get_html($url);
$count = 0;
$goodfiles = array();

    if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
        foreach($html->find('img') as $img){
            $count++;
        }
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

echo $count;

}
```

}

for a lot of websites I receive a count of how many images are on the websites. But for example for the website pinterest.com I receive the following error:

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.pinterest.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/vyrxkian/domains/bblablabla/include/simple_html_dom.php on line 70
 failed 0
```

when I further specify the error I get this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.pinterest.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/vyrxkian/domains/bblablabla/include/simple_html_dom.php on line 70
```

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/vyrxkian/domains/bblablabla.php on line 30
```

how can I prefend this error and read for example pinterest.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use CURL library:

```
$url =  $_POST['form_url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7); 
$resultHtml = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process
curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($resultHtml);
```

Comment: I receive the following error:

     Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in

also, when I var_dump the $html I get an output, but it doesn't look complete.

Comment: I've made an example at http://www.itemmized.com/test/test
there you can see that he can scrape a lot of sites, but for example pinterest he doesn't want to scrape. i don't know why because the function is working. |

When I use curl, like above, the for example I can't scrape my own site (http://www.itemmized.com/test) anymore. When I don't use curl, I can scrape this site. Very strange problem.....